# /etc/init.d/functions weirdness

Tags: fedora, init.d

OS: fedora 15.

seems something has gone awry inside my /etc/init.d/functions file.

i can still stop/start/restart services and daemons using /etc/init.d/restart, but the output is no longer showing my the [OK] and [FAILED] message.

example:

:) root@boxxy:/etc/init.d# /etc/init.d/smb restart
Restarting smb (via systemctl):
:) root@boxxy:/etc/init.d#

the services DO stop and start properly, but there is no output, so im a little confused.

Comment: Paste your SAMBA init script into pastebin and insert link here.

Comment: its actually not samba thats acting up, its any and all services/daemons. i just picked samba at random since it wouldnt hurt me too bad to restart it at the time.

Answer (score 1):

FC15 uses systemd (as the output indicates) not the classic init style any more. You should read up on the init system as there are quite some changes...